# Image Variation endpoint for Openai API

Tags: javascript, cors, openai-api

I'm trying to generate a variation of my image using openai's image variation api endpoint. It throws CORS error

Suggest me a solution using vanilla js.

This is the code snippet, that i have tried

```
requestImageVariation(image) { //image is base64 url of png image

        let data = {
            image: image,
            n: 4
        }

        const options = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
        },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        };

        fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/images/variations", options)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res =>console.log(res))
            .catch(err=>console.log(err))

    }
```

As im getting the image from canvas element, base64 is easier. Suggest me if i should change this img type

If you have any other alternate way of sending the image for the API, please let me know

Comment: do you run your project on local server  ?

Comment: yes @MohamedMostafa, currently it is on localhost

Answer (score 0):

you can try running you project on local server :

```
// shell commands
npm install --global http-server
```

then navigate to your project directory and run :

```
 http-server
```

Comment: im not yet familiar with node.js
i would like to go with vanilla js. Is there any way to achieve this in vanilla js? without the help of Node or any other backend?

Comment: well . I got it .. try the option i posted on the second answer

Answer (score 0):

In situations like these, you can consider using a proxy service to bypass the CORS issue while still keeping everything client-side. There are third-party services available that act as a proxy to make requests on behalf of your frontend application and handle CORS headers. One such service is CORS Anywhere (https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/).

```
function requestImageVariation(image) {
    const data = {
        image: image,
        n: 4,
    };

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', // Required for CORS Anywhere
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    };

    const proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
    const apiUrl = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/images/variations';

    fetch(proxyUrl + apiUrl, options)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => console.log(res))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: statusText: "Forbidden"
type: "cors"

am still getting issues

Comment: So you're saying there is no way to post an image from vanilla to API without using thirdparty services?

Comment: I guess yes .. for my further knowledge